# Workstations connected to SBS 2011 can not connect to "http://connect/" and are getting frequently disconnected or kicked off of the shared drives

Tags: iis-7, dhcp, dhcp-server, windows-sbs-2011

Small Office, there are 7 computers and a server running SBS 2011.

2 workstations are not currently bound to the server, because after recently reinstalling windows 7 on them, it was discovered that nothing is able to reach http://connect/.

1 computer has windows 8, and there has not been any connectivity issues in regards to shared drives, but like the others, it can not reach "connect" from a browser. The other computers are windows 7 and have been experiencing connection issues.

I have no problem reaching IIS7 from any computer by entering the IP address.

"connect" returns a 404, but if I try and access it from the server itself, it returns a 404.

The "fix my network" wizard in the 2011 standard console does not change anything.

BPA does not find any non-compliances.

Any ideas are much appreciated. I've been at it for weeks now.

Update: This morning the disconnect issue happened on the windows 8 computer. This is new, I had to disable/reenable the network adapter in order to reconnect it to the shared drive.

If there is any information that I can provide in order to help get to the bottom of this, please let me know.

Comment: This is surely a DNS problem. Are the clients in question using the SBS server for DNS and are they using the same DNS suffix as the AD domain? Also, make sure that DHCP on the SBS server is configured to assign the AD domain DNS suffix to the clients. Post-domain join the clients will derive their primary DNS suffix from their domain membership but pre-domain join they won't have one, so you'll need to assign it via DHCP.

Comment: All clients are pointing to the server as the primary DNS. (I've even left the secondary one blank.)

DHCP appears to be set to assign the AD Domain DNS suffix to the clients, however to be completely honest I could be doing it wrong. In the server manager, under IPV4 scope options, the domain is set correctly under "015 DNS Domain Name". If I manually set the DNS suffix on the clients, nothing changes.

Comment: The problem is getting worse. I'm now having trouble connecting to the internet on the windows 8 machine, and the outlook profile on that machine has gotten corrupted (something I forgot to mention that had happened on the other workstations.)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, by the way.

Our comcast router was forcing the IPV6 DNS. I disabled it entirely on the router and now everything works as intended.